# How to check the result of the bash test command inside a python script?

Tags: python, bash, if-statement

I would like to run the bash "test" command inside a python script.

For example, in the bash sell script, this can be done easily as follows.
    #!/bin/bash

```
if ! test -s ${file}; then
  echo "${file} does not have a positive size. "
  # Do some processing.. 
fi
```

With a python script, I think I may try the following way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subrocess

try:
  subprocess.check_call("test -s " + file, shell=True)
except:
  print file + " does not have a positive size. "
  # Do some process
```

Is the above approach a good way? If not, then could you please suggest an appropriate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `shell=True` unless it's necessary. Here, you can use `subprocess.check_call(["test","-s",file])` without the security downsides of `shell=True`.

Aside from that, you can use built-ins to python rather than making subprocess calls. For instance, `os` has what you want here:

```
import os
try:
    if os.stat(file).st_size == 0:
        print "File empty." 
except OSError:
    print "File could not be opened."
```